# В чём отличие лексического повтора и форм слова?

Tags: синтаксис

Мне кажется, что это лексический повтор, но он же не повторяет полностью слово? Предложения взяла для примера.

1. *«Грачи прилетели!» — так сказалось, так и назвал он свою картину, ставшую впоследствии знаменитой.*
2. *В этой картине он выразил всё, что томило его, чего ожидал он с таким нетерпением, - первое дуновение весны.*

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае это не лексический повтор, а тавтология. Лексический повтор означает, что полностью повторяется определенный фрагмент или слово, но этого недостаточно. В большинстве случаев лексический повтор применяется в стихотворных текстах и нужен для большей выразительности (повторяются начала или концы строк или применяется анадиплозис).

Для тавтологии не важно, в какой форме стоит слово. Не путать с плеоназмом: там рядом располагаются различные синонимичные слова. Тавтология – ошибка, плеоназм и лексический повтор – художественные приемы.

Comment: А где вы увидели тавтологию? Привидите пример, пожалуйста.